# Programmatically resizing and Scrolling NSView after application launch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, resize, nsview

I want to create a simple application which performs some calculations and then draws some images on view. I use NSBezierPath. Then I must resize the view and allow people scroll the finished picture. But i don't know how.If I also try to draw an image on an invisible part of canvas then it becomes invisible or isn't drawn (I couldn't know the future canvas size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Apple sample code called [BezierPathLab](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/BezierPathLab/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008880).  I think that will get you started.  There's lot of other sample code for Quartz 2D drawing too.

Being able to scroll and resize the view should be as simple as putting the view that you will be using to draw inside an [NSScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScrollView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004101).

Comment: thanks. The problem was the following one. I tried to add another view into scrollview and then i tried to resize it.